# How can I add object programmatically before storyboard objects in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, background, sdk

I'm making login screen with video background
But after I added my background all the Main.storyboard code gets behind my video (video goes on top) how can I bring video to back of my view?

Code :

```
 var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?
    let myPlayerView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    myPlayerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    view.addSubview(myPlayerView)


    var urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: "m4v")
    let url:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)!


    let myPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    myPlayer.play()


    let avLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: myPlayer)
    avLayer.frame = myPlayerView.bounds
    myPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(avLayer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this at the appropriate place. e.g. `viewWillAppear`.

```
myPlayerView.superview?.sendSubviewToBack(myPlayerView)
```